# How To Handle Tasks and variables in router File in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have Browse the web and prepare a router file for my component com_listing by using instruction on following link

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=611587

Here is my code of router file

```
function listingBuildRoute(& $query)
{


     $segments = array();

       if(isset($query['view']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['view'];
                unset( $query['view'] );
       }





       if(isset($query['task']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['task'];
                unset( $query['task'] );
       };


       if(isset($query['id']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
                unset( $query['id'] );
       };

        if(isset($query['type']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['type'];
                unset( $query['type'] );
       };

       return $segments;



}

function listingParseRoute($segments)
{


   $vars = array();
       switch($segments[0])
       {
               case 'accomodation':
                       $vars['view'] = 'accomodation';
                        $id = explode( ':', $segments[2] );
                       $vars['type'] = (int) $id[0];
                       break;
               case 'entertainment':
                       $vars['view'] = 'entertainment';
                       $id = explode( ':', $segments[2] );
                       $vars['type'] = (int) $id[0];
                       break;

       }


        switch($segments[1])
       {
               case 'listing':
                       $vars['task'] = 'listing';
                       $vars['task'] =$segments[1];

                       break;
               case 'details':
                       $vars['task'] = 'details';
                       $vars['task'] =$segments[1];

                       break;

       }


       return $vars;




}
```

It is preparing the URL Successfully as say for a task "listing" and variable "type" the URl is

```
index.php/component/listing/entertainment/listing/11
```

but it is not actuly going in the task listing.It is just showing the view entertainment.I think parse route function is not calling properly But i am not reaching to the correct solution.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$item-­>query['view']`like [this example](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)